# will there be an unique id for each record in Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc

In my application I have created a column with sequence to have unique id for each and every record that I add,I doubt will there be any unique row-number created by oracle itself for every record we updated in table,if yes then how to access that row number like

```
SELECT row-number from table where employee_name='name';
```

here I want to get unique row number created by oracle,

I have searched on net but haven't got proper information

Comment: Why would you need that? Use the primary key. That's what it's for: uniquely identify the row.

Comment: thank you...i could , but i have to do crud operations from ui by connecting to any oracle data base,so i cannot create primary key to all tables,so even the table might not have a primary key i have to achieve this,so i felt oracle internally should have a rownum ]for every record for allowing us to delete record from ui, can we access that row number... is my doubt

Comment: There is rowid, but how that is relevant to you/your front end in doing CRUD operations is beyond me; if you have duplicate rows, how do you distinguish which row needs updating/deleting? If all rows matching that criteria need to be updated, rowid is ... well, irrelevant. Oh, and a given row is not guaranteed to keep the same rowid thoughout its lifetime.

Comment: not a problem i was not updating all records at once i will delete records individually without any criteria like he will click delete button next to that row... just for reference i have added above query.. after seeing your comment i plan to go as delete  from table where rownum='some number'; can this be possible

Comment: `rowid` is the only thing you can use.

Comment: but rowid is retuning some alphabetical value like AAAD6uAAEAAAAOtAAe    @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I'm understanding this question as : besides existance of the primary key, I would like to have a unique number. How to get that ? This would assume your primary key is NOT a number, and for some reason you want a number, not a character string, or an alfanumeric value. Please confirm that. `ROWID` is indeed a column that exists automatically, is unique, but it's not a number. In addition, it's not really easy to read as well. That may be on purpose, as - if your data model is designed correctly - no end-user ever should read Rowid from any table. It's designed for DBA purposes.

Comment: If you have 12c, you can have a column that is PK and a sequence all integrated in one. Obviously, that is at design phase.

Comment: not a problem even it is a alphanumeric also, will this unique rowid will be constant for a record once it got created or will it change from time to time like if new data added to that table.. or if any edit taken place to existing data.. @tvCa

Comment: I meant to say, the OP asks for a unique number, not a unique alfanumeric. The PK also is an alfanumeric (otherwise the OP would use the PK, assuming it is numeric). Choosing one unique alfanumeric over another unique alfanumeric, doesn't help at all in context of the question in OP. The PK is also auto-inserted, like Rowid.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle does maintain a ROWID for each row; however, in my opinion using ROWID in user-written code is both poor practice and dangerous. ROWID is only guaranteed to be constant for the duration of a single transaction. ROWID is *not* guaranteed to be constant forever and the database can change it if and when it determines that a change is necessary. If your data does not supply a value or combination of values which are unique and unchanging I strongly suggest you learn how to create an artificial key which is automatically set using sequences and triggers. I believe 12c supplies auto-increment columns which you can use if you're using the latest version of Oracle.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: I think SQL Developer does use `rowid` as well to create update statements for data that is edited. For the intended purpose (updating rows through a GUI) it is perfectly acceptable to use it even from client code.

Comment: @Horse, how does the use of one tool versus another, changes data integrity ? I seriously doubt the logic behind what you're explaining, as any table (in a correct data structure) has got a unique reference (the PK), and which is also constant. The latter may not be for `rowid`. Can you explain that some more ?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 unique identifiers in Oracle named as ROWNUM and ROWID. You can use them in such ways:-

```
SELECT ROWNUM 
FROM table 
WHERE employee_name = 'name';
```

and

```
SELECT ROWID
FROM table 
WHERE employee_name = 'name';
```

You can read further about them.

Rownum -
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/pseudocolumns008.htm

Rowid - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Comment: i have tried rownum for any query it is returning only 1 and when i use rowid it is returning some alphabetical order like AAAD6uAAEAAAAOtAAe..

Comment: `rownum` is **not** a "unique" identifier. It is *generated* during retrieval and cannot be used for an `update` later on.

Comment: can i use rowid as a unique identifier.. @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: If you want an unique identifier, better to use sequence. Read More - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_6014.htm

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I accepted but it is a unique number throughout a single query..

Comment: i already used sequence in my application.. but i was trying weather there is any other way like rowid... @AnkitBajpai

Comment: Then rowid is definitely a unique  alpha-numeric combo. And it will remain constant throughout the transaction.

Comment: @Horse; Aren't you confusing `unique` with `consistent` ? I would be surprised if Rowid is not unique. To be clear on the definition : `unique` means that no duplicates are found. It doesn't mean the values don't change.

Comment: In last comment, Rowid -> Rownum